# what is the reason that unix is faster than oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, unix

[This article](http://www.analyticbridge.com/group/codesnippets/forum/topics/code-to-help-business-analysts) claims that by running a sql script in unix, it can perform 20x faster?

How can this be possible?

Comment: This is a very open-ended question..

Comment: your question is wrong according to what I can quickly see from this article. This is not unix vs Oracle but unix vs Toad or other clients.

Comment: The claim is that executing certain queries from a Perl script runs 20x faster than executing them from "Brio" or "Toad", which I've not heard of but in context appear to be web-based SQL interfaces perhaps akin to mysqladmin.  So it's not so much Unix vs Oracle as text vs HTML, perhaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like the author is comparing Apples to Oranges (no that's too similar, how about Apples to Aliens).  The performance they speak of comes form the result set being displayed in a browser (as a table)

> instead of waiting for hours for Brio or Toad to return results in a
>   browser (with a crash if the number of rows being returned was above
>   50,000)

As compared to the result set being displayed in a text file (who is to say that a text editor won't crash as well?)

> then export to the Unix station) and produced as output the results of
>   the query (tab-separated text file)

Comment: The original article isn't terribly well written but seems to describe a sensible process improvement for certain business-analysis jobs that could stand to get more attention in the relevant community - that's exactly what blog posts are for.

Comment: sorry zack, I deleted my comment before you post. And you're right on this one that's why i removed it.